# Trying to do bubble sort

Tags: c

I think this is C. but trying to figure out why my bubble sort isn't working. I was following an existing example so perhaps my integration with this code isn't right but not too sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("%s <student-id>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    int i;
    int size = 10000;
    int seed = atoi(argv[1]); 

    srand(seed % 4);

    int *int_array = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int_array[i] = rand();
    }

    // This part
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i += 1) {
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && int_array[j] > int_array[j + 1]; j+= 1) {
            swap(int_array,j);
        }
    }


    int failed = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (int_array[i] < int_array[i+1])
        {
            failed = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    free(int_array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `srand(seed % 4);` - why on earth would you do that? You are limiting your seed to only 4 possible values (0, 1, 2, 3).. why?

Comment: Well, do you compile it as C? Then yes, it is C. Anyway, don't tag with multiple languages, be decisive!

Comment: What is `swap(int_array,j);`?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for bubble sort:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 1) 
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < size; j+= 1) 
    {
        //this for starts from i+1 because I want to compare element int_array[i] whith the rest of the array. Each time this for starts, int_array is sorted from 0 to i-1
        if(int_array[i] > int_array[j]) swap(int_array[i], int_array[j]);
    }
}
```